# Android action bar 'back' causes OnDestroy but device 'back' button does not when exiting preference activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an app with an Activity.  Within the activity, I use a dialog fragment to set some local variables (these variables DO have default values).  I also have an action bar with the "3-dot" icon which allows the user to set some preferences (shared preferences).

All of this works (i.e. variables are getting set correctly via the dialog, shared preferences are getting set via the PreferenceActivity) but there is a lifecycle problem I am experiencing:

When I use the dialog to set the local variables, then change the shared preferences via the action bar 3-dot icon > settings, there are two different results that I am seeing after I'm done editing these settings in the app:
    1. If I use the 'back' button on the phone (Google Nexus 5), all of my local variables are preserved like I would hope.
    2. If I use the 'back' button in the action bar at the top, my local variables are being reset to default values.

While debugging, I see that when I tap the action bar 'back' button from within the preferences screen, the OnDestroy method of the original activity is being executed, and OnCreate is being re-executed.  So bottom line, I know why my variables are being re-set (because my original activity and updated local variables are being destroyed and a new instance is being created), but I don't know why the action bar 'back' functionality seems to behave fundamentally differently than the phone's back button.  I have tried changing the launchmode in the manifest but that has not changed the behavior.  I also have been all over the interwebs/the android developer site and can't seem to find anything.

I could work around this, but would really like to be able to use the action bar back button because I think it is more intuitive and would like it to behave like the phone's back button.  Any help/explanation would be awesome!

main activity (irrelevant code has been removed for brevity):

```
    public class fretboard_flashcards extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener {
        public static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 0;
        [declare local variables here and set to default values]

        @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                [update local variables here via FragmentManager - this works just fine]
        }

        @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.settings_fretboard_flashcards, menu);
                return true;
            }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_settings:
                    Intent i = new Intent(this, settings_activity_fretboard_flashcards.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_SETTINGS);
                    break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if(requestCode==RESULT_SETTINGS)
            {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                handPosition = sharedPreferences.getString("pref_handPosition", "0");
            }
        }
    }
```

Preference Activity:

```
    public class settings_activity_fretboard_flashcards extends PreferenceActivity {

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action bar button and the on device button are fundamentally different. The actual philosophy is that the action bar button is not Back but Up, that is the child activity is destroyed and it goes back to its hierarchical parent. The on device Back button is just that Back. It is a stack of your navigation history in the app. Like the back button in a browser. This behaviour is actually documented by Google. I don't remember the exact link. I will post the link as soon as I can find it.

Found the link
http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html